# Android thread handler always null

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm trying to write an android app to monitor an outdoor propane burner, mainly for tonkotsu ramen, which requires simmering pork for many hours. I have an Arduino  circuit that can detect a flame and send out UDP packets if the flame ever gets blown out or the burner runs out of propane. I've never written an android app, so I find myself getting stuck on basic android principals. I created a `Service` called `HamNet` - for monitoring the ham. `HamNet` has a `ArduinoUDPListener` (`Thread`). I need to send events from the `ArduinoUDPListener` thread to the `MainActivity`, so I created a `Handler` in the main UI thread, and pass that `mHandler` to `netService` when it's started, but for some reason `mainThreadHdlr` is always null when it comes time to send the monitoring data to the main UI thread. Am I misunderstanding android thread handlers? How many do I need to instantiate? Am I even supposed to pass them around from thread to thread?

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private Handler mHandler;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
             @Override
             public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
                 System.out.println("Got msg!");
                 super.handleMessage(inputMessage);
             }
         };
         netService = new HamNet();
         netService.startNetwork(getApplicationContext(), mHandler);
     }

     private HamNet    netService;
 }

 public class HamNet extends Service {

     private Handler mainThreadHdlr;

     public void startNetwork(Context context, Handler hdlr) {
         Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,HamNet.class);
         context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
         mainThreadHdlr = hdlr;
         assert mainThreadHdlr != null;
     }

     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         System.out.println("-=-=-=-=- onStartCommand()");

         udpListener = new ArduinoUDPListener();
         udpListener.start();

         return START_STICKY;
     }

     private class ArduinoUDPListener extends Thread {

         public void run() {
             System.out.println("-=-=-=-=- ArduinoUDPListener.run()");

             if (mainThreadHdlr != null) {
                 Message msg = mainThreadHdlr.obtainMessage();
                 msg.obj = update;
                 mainThreadHdlr.sendMessage(msg);
                 System.out.println("sent msg!");
             } else {
                 System.out.println("null?");
             }
         }

     }

     private ArduinoUDPListener udpListener;
 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it happens because you initialize your handler AFTER starting the service:

```
context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
mainThreadHdlr = hdlr;
```

Method `startForegroundService` invokes overridden `onStartCommand` method which in turn uses your uninitialized handler

Comment: looks like it, but I don't see how I can avoid that.

Comment: why don't you simply initialize the handler before invoking "startForegroundService"